# Using streamreader I can read the next line of words, but can I read the previous one?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, streamreader

Can I read the previous line using StreamReader?

```
Dim previousfile As New StreamReader("file.txt")

If previousfile.Peek <> +1 Then
    txtName.text = previousfile.ReadLine
End If
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at the `BaseStream` property of the StreamReader and it's `Seek` method.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot read the previous line - StreamReader really is a forward only type of reader. when you read a line... thats it. you cannot go back. 
why dont you hold the previous line being read in a temp variable or maybe use the FileStream which has a Seek method which maybe of some use to you?

or why not read the entire contents into a collection of strings and splitting it on some delimeter for example?

Comment: How about if I want to read the first segment or the last segment? is it possible?

Comment: like I said - you cannot read the previous line. I also suggested using a FileStream or reading the entire file into a collection and then you can access any element you want in that collection. First, second...nth.

Comment: While the StreamReader only reads forward, you may be able to call the Seek method of the BaseStream property in order to reposition the stream.  If you know how far back to go:  `streamReaderInstance.BaseStream.Seek(...)`.   It also depends on whether or not the base stream is seekable.  A file stream, for example, should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read backwards with a `StreamReader`, but if you read all of the lines in first you can traverse them however you like. This does mean reading the whole file in up front, which may be less efficient depending on your usage, but [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would do the job and give you an array:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: How about if I want to read the first segment or the last segment? is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "segment?"

Comment: I mean if the file is like a query and have 2 or more textbox to show results, is there any coding which allows me to look around? Like directly display the first input or directly displays the last input?

Comment: I'm still not really clear what you mean. What would the "first input"/"last input" be? If you need to parse the file somehow then you can either split the array of lines however you need to, or read the file using a different method.